# XML DTD elements with the same children

Tags: xml, dtd

this is getting to my brain so i have a XML doc that has a node called family

```
<family>
  <parents>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <init>R</init>
    <surname>Johnson</surename>
  </parents>
  <kids>
    <name>Lucy</name>
    <surname>Johnson</surname>
  </kids>
</family>
```

the inital is optional so i create the DTD for this it ends up looking like

```
<!ELEMENT parent (name, initial?, surname)>
<!ELEMENT kid (name, initial?, surname)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT initial (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT surname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT initial (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT surname (#PCDATA)>
```

but i keep getting this error validity error : Redefinition of element name ^ /tmp/tmp.dtd:26: validity error : Redefinition of element initial ^ /tmp/tmp.dtd:27: validity error : Redefinition of element surname ^

even if i change the DTD to look like this.

```
<!ELEMENT parent (name, initial?, surname)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT initial (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT surname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT kid (name, initial?, surname)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT initial (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT surname (#PCDATA)>
```

same error.. this is literally the second day i am using xml and from the tutorials i have read i cant seem to see what i am doing wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to declare the `name`, `initial` and `surname` twice, just try

```
<!ELEMENT parent (name, initial?, surname)>
<!ELEMENT kid (name, initial?, surname)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT initial (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT surname (#PCDATA)>
```

`parent` and `kid` share the same definitions for their three (or two) child elements.  Given an additional definition of

```
<!ELEMENT family (parent*, kid*)>
```

this would validate the following (corrected from the document you included in the question)

```
<family>
  <parent>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <initial>R</initial>
    <surname>Johnson</surname>
  </parent>
  <kid>
    <name>Lucy</name>
    <surname>Johnson</surname>
  </kid>
</family>
```

Comment: wow really i was jsut thinking that that would really slim down my DTD thanks for the tip i can see that its working now!